# is it legit calculation of time complexity

Tags: c, time-complexity

I have the following function, and I need to find the Theta Notation:

```
void aux(int n){
    for(int i = n; i>2; i = sqrt(i))
        printf("*");}
void f1(int n){
aux(n);
aux(n*n);
aux(n*n*n);}
```

I can assume that sqrt(i) has the time complexity of Theta(1).

I watch the series as it goes like that:

```
i = n^(1/(2^0)), n^(1/(2^1)), n^(1/(2^2)), ... , n^(1/(2^k))
```

and there for:

```
2 = n^(1/2^k) -> 1/2^k = log(n) -> 1/log(n) = 2^k
```

and now:

```
k = log(1/log(n)) = log((log(n))^(-1)) = -1*log(log(n)) =Theta(log(log(n))
```

I do know that the final solution IS Theta(log(log(n)) but I want to know that my calculation is correct and it's ok to say that:

```
-1*log(log(n)) = Theta(log(log(n))
```

Comment: I did look up at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm?rq=1 but I would like to know about my calculation.

Comment: You realize this is integer fixed point arithmetic, yeah? `n^(1/2^i)` gives `n^0` gives `1` for the vast majority of your calculations.

Comment: Yes, I just want to show the series, and how I proceed with my calculation

Comment: But none of it makes sense in a C programming context, because you aren't using floating point. The compiler may be smart enough to inline the sqrt call and then you can toss all timing calculations out the window, because a loop like `for(int i = n; i>2; i = 1)` will just be removed and the only thing remaining of your program after optimization is some printf call printing a star.

Comment: I really don't understand how is this relevant to my question. all I asked that if it' ok to assume that `-1*log(log(n)) = Theta(log(log(n))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there might be a mistake in the calculations. The working in the question shows

```
2 = n^(1/2^k) -> 1/2^k = log(n) -> 1/log(n) = 2^k
```

However

```
2 = n^(1/2^k) -> 1/2^k = log(base n) 2 -> log(n) = 2^k
```

So you get `k=+log(logn)` and not `-log(logn)`. Negative time complexity would mean your program takes negative time to run.

So, yeah, the algo is theta(log(logn))